# Toggle Fullscreen mode

Tags: android, fullscreen

I need some help toggling fullscreen mode. I have a setting in a preference screen to go fullscreen. In my main activity's onResume I have:

```
if(mFullscreen == true) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

            } else
            {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            }
```

But this doesn't seem to work because it needs to be called before `setContentView` right?

... But Also, I have `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView` and it takes away the title AND status bar... Can anybody offer some help?

---Edit---
Ok, I had a bug that was causing this to not work. So it actually does. Now, I just need to know how to toggle the title bar.

Answer (score 30):

```
private void setFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
{
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    else
    {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * toggles fullscreen mode
 * <br/>
 * REQUIRE: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
 * <pre>
 * sample:
 *     private boolean fullscreen;
 *     ................
 *     Activity activity = (Activity)context;
 *     toggleFullscreen(activity, !fullscreen);
 *     fullscreen = !fullscreen;
 * </pre>
 */
private void toggleFullscreen(Activity activity, boolean fullscreen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
        // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
        int uiOptions = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
                ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
            Log.i(context.getPackageName(), "Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
        } else {
            Log.i(context.getPackageName(), "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
        // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
        // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
        // all three flags are being toggled together.
        // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is referred to as "sticky".
        // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and status bars
        // semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user interacts with
        // the screen.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
    } else {
        // for android pre 11
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (fullscreen) {
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        } else {
            attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        activity.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    }

    try {
        // hide actionbar
        if (activity instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
            if (fullscreen) ((ActionBarActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar().hide();
            else ((ActionBarActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar().show();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            if (fullscreen) activity.getActionBar().hide();
            else activity.getActionBar().show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // set landscape
   // if(fullscreen)  activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
   // else activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
}
```

my code working fine with android 2.3 and 4.4.2

Comment: Great up-to-update method! Two things though: 1) newUiOptions modifications are missing the non-fullscreen "&= ~xxx" parts, 2) Latest appcompat lib uses AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 7):

Since Jellybean (4.1) there is a new method that doesn't rely on the WindowManager. Instead use setSystemUiVisibility off of the Window, this gives you more granular control over the system bars than using WindowManager flags. This is how you enable fullscreen:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) { //ye olde method
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else { // Jellybean and up, new hotness
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

And this is how you revert the above code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) { //ye olde method
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else { // Jellybean and up, new hotness
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
}
```

Comment: Note that you may need to call `getSupportActionBar()` instead.

Comment: I use this method，on huawei machine statusbar has hide but the view can not auto adjust location to the top of screen

Answer (score 5):

There's a shorter toggle full screen method implementation:

```
private void toggleFullscreen() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

It uses bitwise XOR logic to toggle `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`.

Comment: Does not hide the navigation bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

My solution combines answers from:

- cprcrack's answer to this question
- [Holoeverywhere : how to programmatically remove at runtime the action bar from an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343979)
- [Android: Programmatically detect if device has hardware menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907)

I added these methods to my Activity.  To toggle full screen, use `setFullScreen(!isFullScreen())`.

```
public boolean isFullScreen() {

    return (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setFullScreen(boolean full) {

    if (full == isFullScreen()) {
        return;
    }

    Window window = getWindow();
    if (full) {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        if (full) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        } else {
            getActionBar().show();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I wanted a menu button to do the toggling.  The problem: on a device without a hardware menu button, hiding the action bar also hides the toggle to return from full screen.  So, I added some extra logic so it only hides the action bar if the device has a hardware menu button.  Note that devices running SDK 11-13 did not have one.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 
        && ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey()))) {

        if (full) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        } else {
            getActionBar().show();
        }
    }
```

Older devices (running Gingerbread or earlier) have a Title Bar instead of an Action Bar.  The following code will hide it, but be aware that the Title Bar cannot be shown/hidden once the activity has started.  I included a message to the user in my help menu stating that changes to full screen may not take full effect on older devices until they restart the app/activity (which of course assumes you persist their selection and execute this code only if they want it full screen).

```
    // call before setContentView()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution for the fullscreen.

```
if (isFullscreen) {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity?.window!!, root).apply {
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
} else {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity?.window!!, root)
        .show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```