# Holoeverywhere : how to programmatically remove at runtime the action bar from an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-holo-everywhere

Which is the correct way to remove the action bar inside an activity ?

My activity extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity

I've a custom Application class that extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Application and at startup execs this static code :

```
ThemeManager.setDefaultTheme(ThemeManager.DARK);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.DARK, R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.LIGHT,  R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme_Light);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.MIXED, R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme_Light_DarkActionBar);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.DARK | ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN,  R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme_Fullscreen);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.LIGHT | ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN, R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme_Light_Fullscreen);
ThemeManager.map(ThemeManager.MIXED | ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN, R.style.Holo_Demo_Theme_Light_DarkActionBar_Fullscreen);
```

in my activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ThemeManager.removeTheme(this);
    setTheme(ThemeManager.DARK | ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

if I add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` in the code, on an `android 4.1.1` -table- the bar is removed
 while on an handset `-android 2.3.3`- the bar is not removed.

Before introducing holoeverywhere everything worked fine with just `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE).`

Which is the correct way to remove at runtime the actionbar in holoeverywhere ?
(I want to do it at runtime because the user has the option to set a DARK or LIGHT layout, with a DARK default)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See flag ThemeManager.NO_ACTION_BAR.
Or just call

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: It also works with setTheme(ThemeManager.DARK | ThemeManager.NO_ACTION_BAR) ; I was using ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN instead of NO_ACTION_BAR

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programatically:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

I added some lines so that you can show it in fullscreen, as it seems that's what you want.

Comment: thanks for answer, but in your example you're not using the holoeverywhere library, but the "pure" android SDK...

Comment: Oh sorry i oculdn't help you out. I replied with whatever i had knowledge of.

Comment: With pure SDK everything works. After I introduced the library I have this problem. I think it's a "stupid" problem, but the library has NO documentation at all !

Comment: Thanks for the answer... This prevented me from not supporting a few API versions :-)

Comment: When I do this, I am left with a blank white rectangle where the action bar would have been.  What have I done wrong? Thanks.